# nginx 301 redirect not working for 443 ssl, why..?

Tags: ssl, redirect, nginx

I'm trying to redirect from an old domain to a new one.

The old domain used to have an SSL cert, but it doesn't any more.

So I need to 301 redirect these:

- `http://olddomain.co.uk`
- `http://www.olddomain.co.uk`
- `https://olddomain.co.uk`
- `https://www.olddomain.co.uk`

All to: `https://www.newdomain.co.uk`

This is my config:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  listen       443 ssl;
  server_name  olddomain.co.uk www.olddomain.co.uk;
  return       301 https://www.newdomain.co.uk;
}
```

I'm using http://www.redirect-checker.org to test.

Both of the `http` URL's redirect fine, however the `https` URL's are not found at all, as if this server directive doesn't catch the `https` URL's.

- Is that because I need an SSL cert even though I'm not serving anything..?
- Is an SSL cert still needed, just to redirect..?
- If not, why would this not work..?

**EDIT**

To be clear, I don't see cert errors, Chrome says "This site can't be reached", it does't say anything about a cert. redirect-checker.org says "no URLs found".

**EDIT 2**

I've found another `.conf` file, which is working (all 4 url's, inc 2 `https`, redirecting, without a cert installed). This is copy-pasted:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      443 ssl;
    server_name thepreventduty.com www.thepreventduty.com;
    return 301  $scheme://www.thepreventduty.co.uk$request_uri;
}
```

These all redirect:

- `http://thepreventduty.com`
- `http://www.thepreventduty.com`
- `https://thepreventduty.com`
- `https://www.thepreventduty.com`

To `https://www.thepreventduty.co.uk`, and I don't have an ssl cert for `thepreventduty.com`.

You can see if works here: http://www.redirect-checker.org/

When I add another `.conf` for another domain (I'm using `include websites/*.conf;` in `nginx.conf`), exact same `server` directive, just the domain names changed - it doesn't work!

Why..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTPS connection means HTTP connections in SSL-session.
For establishing SSL-session you need certificate and key.

From official site of nginx:

> To configure an HTTPS server, the ssl parameter must be enabled on listening sockets in the server block, and the locations of the server certificate and private key files should be specified

So, you need specify locations of certificate and key.
In case of incorrect SSL you will get cert error before redirect.

I recommend you use acme.sh for getting valid certificate and key.

At first, you need temporary disable redirects and specify root directory of old domain.

Then follow instruction:
https://github.com/Neilpang/acme.sh

Once it is done, enable redirect back.

Comment: Ok, now I'm confused. I've checked, and I actually have another conf on this server that seems to be working, redirecting without a cert. I'll update my question now... (I'm on Windows btw)

Comment: I just added another conf file in edit 2 above. So how do you explain the fact that I'm redirecting from `thepreventduty.com` to `thepreventduty.co.uk`, and there is no ssl cert for the `.com` domain..?

Comment: You are right, there is no SSL-cert for thepreventduty.com.
Nginx uses certificate for  www.cltest01.co.uk .

Comment: The issue may be in name of config file (it should be like websites/domain**.conf**), also, old_domain should be pointed to IP of  thepreventduty.com.

Comment: Right, ok... I'm even more confused now... Why would nginx use the cert from cltest01.co.uk, that cert is only for that domain, and is only referenced in the `server` directive for that domain.

Comment: I didn't know the config file name mattered, I thought using `include websites/*.conf;` would just inc all `conf`s, no matter what they're called. Do you have a link to any docs about this `.conf` naming..?

Comment: Once you connect to https://olddomain , browser trying establish ssl-connection and gets SSL-cert for cltest01.co.uk instead of olddomain. 
So, you see cert error in browser. 

When you use `include websites/*.conf;` directive, all files should be named as `olddomain.conf`. 
If in websites dir located only files containing `server {....}`, you may use `include websites/* ;`